# Getting the number of same elements in both arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I need to count the number of values that both arrays have.

```
def process_2arrays(arr1, arr2)
  length1 = arr1.count
  length2 = arr2.count
  arr3 = []
  i = 0
  while length1 >= i do
    ci = arr1[i]
    if arr2.include?(ci)
      arr3 << ci
      damn = arr3.count 
      i = i + 1
    end 

    return [(damn), (2), (3), (4)]
  end
end
```

When I pass the values to the function it returns [nil, 2, 3, 4] 
Whats the problem here?

Comment: Unrelated, but please indent your code for legibility.

Answer (score 4):

To find elements that exist in both arrays, use the set intersection method `&`.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26

```
def count_same_elements(a1,a2)
    (array1 & array2).length
end
```

Example

```
count_same_elements([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5])
=> 3
```

Comment: I came to say the same. Best answer. I was going to say (a1 & a2).count, not sure which is better. Nevermind, just looked it up, and length is better: http://batsov.com/articles/2014/02/17/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-13-length-vs-size-vs-count/

Answer (score 3):

`damn` is initialized within a `do .. end` block, specifically the while block. Therefore, its value will live within that scope, and when you call the variable outside the block its value is `nil`.

If you want to preserve the value, you must initialize the variable to nil outside the block.

```
i = 0
damn = nil
...
```

As a side note, your code is lacking the most basic Ruby standards. In Ruby you generally use an iterator, not the while. Moreover, you don't use the return at the end of a method.

This is how you would write your method in Ruby using the iterators and taking advantage of some methods from the core library.

```
def process_2arrays(arr1, arr2)
  arr3 = arr1.select { |e| arr2.include?(e) }
  [arr3.size, 2, 3, 4]
end
```

Changing completely approach, you can use

```
def process_2arrays(arr1, arr2)
  (arr1 & arr2).size
end
```